# Show that if $u, v \in V(G)$, $u \not= v$, with $G$ a $k$-critical graph, then $N(u) \not\subseteq N(v)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I tried considering $\chi(G-u) = k-1$ and using the same for $v$, And when I quit a vertex $u$ or $v$ I make a proper partition in $k-1$ color classes, saying that this differ in one the color of exactly the opposite vertex, and thats the color of the color class that contains the vertex that $\in N(v)$ but  $\not\subset N(u)$ but I don't get think my proof is correct, could you give a hint or show how to prove that affirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $N(u)\subseteq N(v).$ Since $G$ is $k$-critical, $G-u$ is $(k-1)$-colorable. Take a proper coloring of $G-u$ with $k-1$ colors, and extend it to $G$ by giving $u$ the same color as $v.$ Since $N(u)\subseteq N(v),$ it is clear that this is a proper coloring of $G$ with $k-1$ colors, contradicting the assumption that $G$ is $k$-chromatic.

Comment: Well, that was quick thanks a lot